# RPi 4 not connecting to Wifi

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-4

I connected my RPi 4 B with Raspbian OS to my home network successfully. After rebooting, it just did not want to connect again. I have re-installed Raspian without any success. It does however, connect to my phone's hotspot. After reading other blog posts, I tried to edit the `etc/wpca_supplicant/wpa_suplicant.conf`, but here I only get a popup:'Can't open file to write' when trying to save. In this config file, there currently is written:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GOUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=ZA

network={
    ssid="myHomeSSID"
    psk="MyHomePassword"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
network={
    ssid="myAndroidAP"
    psk="MyAndroidPassword"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    disabled=1
}
```

Any help that could get me re-connected to my network would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Edit the file using `sudoedit /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. Add a line with `priority=10` underneath your homeSSID. Then `sudo systemctl restart wpa_supplicant` and it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I then deleted all networks from `wpa_supplicant.conf` and rebooted. It then again put the network into the file but could not connect. It can however still connect to my mobile hotspot.

Answer (score 2):

I think I had got the answer. It seems when the RPI4 is working with HDMI monitor plugged in it produces noise. The noise is around 2.4 GHz WiFi's channel 1. The solution is to switch your router to higher channel. I had tested that with my RPI 4, before few minutes and it works.
It seems also that it is known issue for which the company is informed.
I had found the solution [here](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/raspberry-pi-4-wi-fi-not-working).
Hope this helps.

Comment: This was it for me. My router automatically switches the channel to one that is least used among WiFi networks in my building. Sometimes the RPi4 WiFi didn't work for minutes, sometimes hours, sometimes days. It was infuriating, nothing fixed it, and it automatically fixed itself. Changing the WiFi channel to always be at 13 fixed this issue completely.

Answer (score 1):

You give an important detail in a comment: "*I then deleted all networks from wpa_supplicant.conf and rebooted. It then again put the network into the file but could not connect. It can however still connect to my mobile hotspot."* You should edit the question and add it to it.

I seems there is an application that updates `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` but that breaks the communication with your HomeSSID. With the available information it is not clear why but you can disable to update wpa_supplicant.conf. Setup it so you will connect to your HomeSSID and then set

```
update_config=0
```

This will prevent any application to modify wpa_supplicant.conf.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot ofreasons for this. 
1. The country select
2. Service daemon corruption
3. wpa_supplicant.conf has wrong configurations
If any of this doesn't work then flash the sdcard again

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn't set up an static IP address for the raspberry pi. If you change the connection settings like the network, that might break the connection. Check your /etc/dhcpcd.conf file.